# How to Add Custom Validation Error Message for Custom Validator in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, angular-validation

I'm using reactive angular forms and created new custom form validator but its not showing custom messages I wanted to add custom message for custom validator.

I'm trying to ignore static message I want that message to be added in that validator itself so it can show for wherever places I use that validator.

**custom validator codes :**

```
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

export function validateJson(input: FormControl): object | null {
    try {
        if (input.value) {
            JSON.parse(input.value);
        }

        return null;
    } catch (error) {
        return { invalidFormat: true };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

just change `invalidFormat` property's value to object with property message instead of `true`

```
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

export function validateJson(input: FormControl): object | null {
    try {
        if (input.value) {
            JSON.parse(input.value);
        }

        return null;
    } catch (error) {
        return { invalidFormat: {message: "your message here"} };
    }
}
```

and in html if error exists display message like so

```
<div *ngIf="formControl.errors.invalidFormat && formControl.dirty">
        {{ formControl.errors.invalidFormat.message}}
</div>
```

Comment: thanks and yes I tried it but just want to make sure that it is recommended way or not

Comment: yeah I think this is the best way, I couldn't found better way then this so far, also we are using it in all our projects and it works perfect